# getting all individuals of a specific class using OWLAPi and JFact reasoner

Tags: java, owl-api

Is there any way to get all individuals of a specific class using reasoner?
Reasoner because i want to get all the inferred and assereted individuals of that class. 
I am using JFact reasoner, and i am trying for loops and if statement. And i want to find the individuals of class e.g "person". But i am unable to see the individuals. Any idea about below code or is there any method for this purpose?

```
for (OWLClass c : myPizza.getClassesInSignature()) {
        NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> instances = reasoner.getInstances(c, true);
        System.out.println(c.getIRI().getFragment());
        if (c.getIRI().getFragment().equals("Person")){

            for (OWLNamedIndividual i : instances.getFlattened()) {
                System.out.println(i.getIRI().getFragment()); 

        }
    }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        break;

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `reasoner.getInstances(c, true);` will only give you the /direct/ instances of c; if the individuals you are after are instances of subclasses of c, they will be skipped. Switch to `reasoner.getInstances(c, false);` to include instances of subclasses.

You are also calling `break;` after the first iteration. If `person` is not the first class in the signature, you'll never look for instances of `person`.

You could slightly change your code to do less reasoning work:

```
for (OWLClass c : myPizza.getClassesInSignature()) {
    if (c.getIRI().getFragment().equals("Person")){
        NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> instances = reasoner.getInstances(c, false);
        System.out.println(c.getIRI().getFragment());
        for (OWLNamedIndividual i : instances.getFlattened()) {
            System.out.println(i.getIRI().getFragment()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Note from comments, if you expect to see SWRL inferred individuals you need to use a reasoner that supports SWRL, like Pellet or HermiT. JFact does not support SWRL rules.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your codes but I am only getting the asserted Individuals. I am not getting the inferred individuals. Do you know a solution?

Comment: Can you share the ontology?

Comment: by sharing, do u mean i send u the owl file or just some description of my ontology?

Comment: i should mention here that the inferred individuals are generate via swrl rules.

Comment: By sharing I meant to be able to either put the ontology here or a link to it, so that the issue can be reproduced. But your other comment explains the issue: SWRL rules are not supported by JFact, so no inferred individuals are computed by JFact.
Side note: are you generating new instances or just asserting new axioms about existing individuals? SWRL rules cannot create new individuals, if I remember the DL-safe rules correctly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.Yes, u r right , it can not create new individuals.  I have already created individuals, i just wanted the reasoner to compute the swrl rules and put those individuals in some classes according to the rules. Which reasoner do you think is better to compute the swrl rules?

Comment: its really difficult to get Hermit working on android. Did u check it on android?

Comment: No, I've not tried. I have a HermiT fork at https://github.com/ignazio1977/hermit-reasoner - this is not the main HermiT repo, but if you have issues you can report them here and I'll try and see if it's anything easy to fix or not. You can also try the HermiT official page http://hermit-reasoner.com/support.html

Comment: both pellet and Hermit seems to be impossible for me to run on android.

Answer (score 3):

Try out this method. You can get all individuals for a particular class using below method.

```
 private static void printIndividualsByclass(OWLOntology ontology, String owlClass){
    OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new PelletReasonerFactory();
    OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createNonBufferingReasoner(ontology);
    for (OWLClass c : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
        if (c.getIRI().getShortForm().equals(owlClass)){
            NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> instances = reasoner.getInstances(c, false);
            System.out.println("Class : "+ c.getIRI().getShortForm());
            for (OWLNamedIndividual i : instances.getFlattened()) {
                System.out.println(i.getIRI().getShortForm()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```