# Why the inferences visualised in Protege differ from the exported inferred axioms

Tags: ontology, protege, owl-api, inference, reasoning

I have an ontology with two main classes (code and subject) and one object property (subject obtained code) where:

- Code(class) contains all available codes(instances)
- Code's(class) subclasses categorise these codes(instances); manually specified
- Subject(class) contains all available subjects(instances)
- Each subject(instance) has asserted(property obtained) some codes(instances)
- Subject's(class) subclasses define the sets of subjects(instances) according to the associated codes(instances) and codes' code category allegiance
- Reasoner is about to infer assertions of subject instances to particular groups (subject's subclasses)

When I start a reasoner within Protege, inferred instances are asserted to the deepest subject subclass that the instance still meets the constraints (see attached [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmOBy.png)). But if I export inferred axioms into separate ontology, every subject subclass contains all instances of itself + its descendants (obviously, same behaviour is observed using JAVA OWL API).

My question is: Why the results are different? I understand the logic of both cases but I don't understand why they are different. Is there any way to export the inferences as they are shown in Protege? And if there is no direct way, may I force Hermit (or other reasoner) somehow from OWL API to show me exactly the same "yellow protege" results? So far, I've found only one workaround - to export inferences as they are and then ask for differences via SPARQL.

I'm using Protege 5.0.0, Reasoner Hermit 1.3.8 and OWL API 5.0.5 (although same results were obtained for different reasoners: Fact++, Pellet; and different OWL API and Protege versions: 4.x)

I'll be very glad for any comments, even a simple explanation will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The exported axioms depend on the set of inferred axiom generators used - Protege might be using a different set from the one you've chosen.

The set of generators is configurable in a panel; its initialisation looks like this:

```
    addCheckBox(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredEquivalentClassAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredSubObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredSubDataPropertyAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredEquivalentObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredEquivalentDataPropertiesAxiomGenerator(), true, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredObjectPropertyCharacteristicAxiomGenerator(), false, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredDataPropertyCharacteristicAxiomGenerator(), false, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredInverseObjectPropertiesAxiomGenerator(), false, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredClassAssertionAxiomGenerator(), false, false);
    addCheckBox(new InferredPropertyAssertionGenerator(), false, true);
    addCheckBox(new InferredDisjointClassesAxiomGenerator(), false, true);
```

I'm going to guess the selected ones by default are the ones marked with true.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, @Ignazio. But actually, it does not solve my problem. I tried many configurations (in Protege as well as in OWL API), but I've never reached the same state as "live" inferences are visualised by Protege. Moreover, as I can setup a set of generators for axiom exports, I can also setup what inferences will be shown in Protege (highlighted, yellowish). They still differ (in case of inferred instances) even if I let Protege to show and generate instances only.

Comment: There might be more inferencing in protégé, outside what I've found - I know that's true for the non-inferred views. However I'm not familiar enough with protégé to point out any such extras.

Comment: I found a solution in the other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072721/getting-all-individuals-of-a-specific-class-using-owlapi-and-jfact-reasoner/28083605#28083605) of yours. Protege highlighted inferences are probably an output of `reasoner.getInstances(c, true);` (instances of subclasses are skipped). But when the inferred ontology is generated by InferredOntologyGenerator (IOG) object, there is no option like this and thus instances are not skipped. Have you get any idea how to set an IOG to work as `reasoner.getInstances(c, false);`?

Comment: Problem solved. I was using `InferredClassAssertionAxiomGenerator` where the "direct type retrieving condition" is hard-coded as _false_. So I wrote my own generator, where the condition is set to _true_: `reasoner.getTypes(entity, true).entities()
            .forEach(t -> result.add(dataFactory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(t, entity)));`. Thank you @Ignazio !