# Inferencing the Sematincs of Equality (OWL 2 RL) using owlapi

Tags: java, inference, owl-api, reasoner

I'm trying to produce entailment for the rule in OWL 2 RL 'The Semantics of Equality' using owl-api. I already tried to follow: [Why the inferences visualised in Protege differ from the exported inferred axioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585030/why-the-inferences-visualised-in-protege-differ-from-the-exported-inferred-axiom)

```
genInferred.add(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredClassAssertionAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredDisjointClassesAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredEquivalentClassAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredEquivalentDataPropertiesAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredEquivalentObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredInverseObjectPropertiesAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredObjectPropertyCharacteristicAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredPropertyAssertionGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredSubDataPropertyAxiomGenerator());
genInferred.add(new InferredSubObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator());
```

And try to precomputed the same individual inference:

```
reasoner.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.SAME_INDIVIDUAL);
ontologyInf.addAxioms(reasoner.getPendingAxiomAdditions());
```

I already try using Openllet and hermit as reasoner.

But I still can't produce entailment like this:

```
If:
T(?x, owl:sameAs, ?y)
T(?y, owl:sameAs, ?z) 
Then:
T(?x, owl:sameAs, ?z)
```

or anything in Semantics of Equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inferred axiom generator that materialises the `sameAs` relations. You could write one yourself, based e.g., on `InferredPropertyAssertionGenerator`, or you can open an issue on the OWLAPI GitHub repo for the functionality to be added to the library.